# Secure connection failed on Firefox 60

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with certificate of one website.

When I try to go, firefox load the error page of certificate, without say me the problem, only that it can't be load.

If in the last version of Firefox i can bypass, in this new version i can't.

Any solution?
Thanks a lot for the collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using external wifi adapters. If any, it's time to change them.